# Is there a case-insensitive SQL Collation that is vendor-independent?

Tags: sql, collation

I'm using an in-house framework for the application I'm working on. We want to keep it as general as possible. I'd like to make case-insensitive text comparations in an SQL database without tying myself to a specific DB vendor.

From what I've read in many SO questions, specifying a Collation in the query is the way to go. However, I've only found answers that refer to Collations as specific for a DB vendor. Is there a vendor-agnostic Collation, or at least one that will work with most DB vendors?

If there is no such Collation, what other solution/approach would you suggest? Please keep in mind that I want to save case-sensitive data (that is, I want to preserve the cases when I write to the database) and make one case-insensitive = comparation on that text column.

Comment: Other than ms-sql, what other major db vendor is case insensitive?

Comment: you can always make your comparisons upper or lowercase so that case will never matter.  LOWER('ABC') = 'abc'

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm guessing most or all allow case-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: @Matt thanks for the idea. That would require a bit of rework to how our framework does queries, but I can do it. I'd prefer a Collation, but will keep that in mind in case I don't find a better solution. Thanks!